Flutter web no active service worker
I'm working on the release of my application on the web and since the 3.22.2 I've some problem with the service worker.
here is my index.html
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
  <script>
    // Vérifiez que les service workers sont supportés
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        try {
          // Enregistrer le service worker
          const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Service Worker registration or push subscription failed:', error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Service workers are not supported in this browser.');
    }
  </script>
</body>

This is my firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "",
    databaseURL: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Necessary to receive background messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

And this is my dart :
final vapidKeyPreprod = '${dotenv.env['PREPROD_VAPID_KEY_WEB']}';
    final vapidKeyProd = '${dotenv.env['PROD_VAPID_KEY_WEB']}';
    final isProd = DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatformFlavors?.prod != null ? false : true;
    final vapidKey = isProd ? vapidKeyProd : vapidKeyPreprod;

    try {
      final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken(
        vapidKey: currentPlatform.isWeb ? vapidKey : null,
      );

      return fcmToken;
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print(e);
      errorReportingService.reportException(e, stackTrace: stackTrace);

      return null;
    }

Every first time I'm launching my web, I go to the catch and print this :
AbortError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker
Second time it's always working.
I've this problem on localhost, preproduction and production env.
I've follow everything I found but I don't seems to understand why it's not working. All my variable in my sw, env and vapid are correct so I don't get it.
Thank you in advance,

final vapidKeyPreprod = '${dotenv.env['PREPROD_VAPID_KEY_WEB']}';
final vapidKeyProd = '${dotenv.env['PROD_VAPID_KEY_WEB']}';
final isProd = DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatformFlavors?.prod != null ? false : true;
final vapidKey = isProd ? vapidKeyProd : vapidKeyPreprod;
var isFcmTokenSet = false;
var retries = 0;
String? fcmToken;

while (!isFcmTokenSet && retries < 3) {
  try {
    fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken(vapidKey: currentPlatform.isWeb ? vapidKey : null);

    return fcmToken;
  } catch (e) {
    if (fcmToken != null) {
      isFcmTokenSet = true;
    } else {
      retries++;
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }
}
return fcmToken;

}
This is what I did to correct it. I actually did the same with the APNS token for iOS since sometimes it wasn't working.
Cheers,
